# WordPress built-in Custom Background

Tags: theme-options

Is it possible to enable the "Custom Background" function of WordPress (add_custom_background() ) in my own theme-options page?

Thx for helping!

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the theme_support in your functions.php
Simply add this to your functions.php

```
add_custom_background();
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, but you misunderstood my question. I am developing a theme with a massive theme options page. There the user should be able to change the background. So Wordpress has this function out-of-the-box - but if I add your snippet, the custom background is available in the appearance menu. But i want the "Custom Background Feature" in a separate Tab in my own "Theme Options" - Page, with its own Menu in the Backend.

I hope, you'll understand my (bad) english. ;-)

Comment: Puh then you should look what the functions does and maybe load that code into your theme. But I don't see a point in that, except that you have more work to do...

Simply put your theme options all in design submenu and you are done?!

Comment: I would advise against it, it's bad user interface design, it makes all the guides useless, and it's unnecessary work for you ( and complicates your own UI ). To implement this you'll be fighting an uphill battle, and you'll probably have to redo it from scratch in 3.3/3.4 when they change the way options are submitted ( no more POST to options.php )

Comment: Will they change the way options are submitted?

Comment: @TomJNowell I think you're right. WP has this feature out-of-the-box and i will use it. Maybe they will improve this feature in later version to be more customizable. thx for you thought!